# how can i override date validation in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

in my model `gst_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)`
it is an optional field, from UI it sent as gst_date = ""

```
gst_date = null OR remove the gst_date key is working fine
```

my question is how can I handle the empty string from Django serializer itself ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define some fields in serializer class, these fields can be nullable or blank

```
class mySer(serializers.Serializer):
    str = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('str')
```

Comment: now its throws an exception django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Comment: manually checked and updated the validated_data.
now working Thank bro..